# How to solve $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{y^2}{[(x-n\pi)^2+y^2]^{3/2}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation, electromagnetism

I need to solve this sum:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{y^2}{[(x-n\pi)^2+y^2]^{3/2}}.$$
Do you have any ideas for how I could do this?

I know that this sum:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{y}{(x-n\pi)^2+y^2},$$
can be simplified by using the following identities (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem)):
$$\cot(x+iy) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x-n\pi + iy},$$
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{y}{(x-n\pi)^2+y^2}=\frac{i}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x-n\pi+iy}-\frac{1}{x-n\pi-iy}.$$
Hence,
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{y}{(x-n\pi)^2+y^2}&=\frac{i}{2}[\cot(x+iy)-\cot(x-iy)] \\
&=\frac{\sinh(2y)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)}.
\end{aligned}$$

Do you know if a similar trick can be used to solve the original sum?

Comment: Is this from an electrostatics problem? This is more-or-less the $y$-component of the force on a charge located at $(x,y)$ due to an infinite array of unit charges on the $x$-axis spaced a distance $\pi$ apart.

Comment: Yes, it is. I am actually trying to calculate the magnetic field along the axis of symmetry for an infinite number of current-carrying loops spaced $\pi$ apart. You can see the formula I am using [here.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html#c3) Replace $z$ with $x$ and $R$ with $y$ and set all other quantities to 1.

Comment: Well, at the very least you can reduce the power in the denominator by noting that this sum may be written as $-y(d/dy)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\left[{(x-n\pi)}^2 + y^2\right]}^{-1/2}$. Edit: No, that diverges.

Comment: You can also use the Poisson summation formula to write this as a sum over a modified Bessel function of the second kind. (I'm just spitballing here.)

Comment: That's good I want as many ideas as I can get. I'm not sure how the Poisson summation formula works. I'll look it up now.

Comment: I find that Mathematica is unable to solve $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty}{\left(n^2 + 1\right)}^{-3/2}$, so I don't hold high hopes for this to have a closed-form solution.

Comment: I will still be very pleased if we get an answer in terms of analytic expressions.

Comment: This looks like a sum of series by residues but how is a fractional power $(\frac{3}{2})$ dealt with?$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = -\{ sum\, of\, residues\, of\, \pi\cot(\pi z)f(z)\, at\, all\, the\, poles\, of\, f(z) \} \tag{1}$$ Probably Taylor/Laurent expansion?

Comment: @arthur Disregarding an extra factor of $y^2$ in the numerator, this sum can be written as $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} f(n)$, where $f$ is the complex function $f(z) = 1/{|z - c|}^3$ and $c = (x + i y)/\pi$. This function is not analytic, so the rules for analytic functions fail to apply.

Comment: Which, by the way, answers the original question: No, a similar trick _can't_ be used with this sum.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. Do you think we can solve the sum using the Poisson summation formula? I understand the answer might be in terms of the modified Bessel functions (or something like that) but I'm okay with that.

Comment: We can re-write the sum in terms of a sum over modified Bessel functions using the Poisson summation formula, but it doesn't really solve it in any sense. If anything, it makes matters worse, since Bessel functions are harder to deal with than what you already have.